# How to write a proper singleton BOOL function

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to check if user logged in, and try to return a boolean value when login successfull

**Problem:** When I request the boolean it always returns 0 then few seconds later  `ASIHTTPRequest` finishes its request and update the boolean value.

**What I want:** get the boolean value after all requests finishes. I think proper way would be write a boolean function and retrieve the result of asihhtp requests?

in singleton:

```
@interface CloudConnection : NSObject
{
    BOOL isUserLoggedIN;
}
@property BOOL isUserLoggedIN;
+ (CloudConnection  *)sharedInstance;
@end

+ (CloudConnection *)sharedInstance
{
    static CloudConnection *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[CloudConnection alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here

    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //send login request
        [self sendLoginRequest];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) sendLoginRequest{ .....}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{ else if (request.responseStatusCode == 202) {
        //parse  json data
        NSLog(@"Login Succesfull");
        _isUserLoggedIN=YES;
    }
}
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{}
```

In a VC:

```
CloudConnection *sharedInstance=[CloudConnection  sharedInstance];
 NSLog(@"is logged in init %hhd",sharedInstance.isUserLoggedIN);
[self performSelector:@selector( checkLoginAfterFiveSeconds) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

-(void) checkLoginAfterFiveSeconds
{

    CloudConnection *sharedInstance=[CloudConnection  sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"is logged in init %hhd",sharedInstance.isUserLoggedIN);
}
```

**NSLOG:**

```
is logged in init 0
Login Succesfull`
is logged in init 1 //after 5 secs
```

Comment: You are actually asking how to wrap an asynchronous call into a synchronous one. This typically involves using a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

well if you do what you propose, its gonna block the calling thread. and you never want a thread waiting for network traffic **especially not the main / ui thread**

make it a void function and make it call a completionHandler or ... send a NSNotification once the result can be calculated directly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right :)
In your request completion block call this method:

```
[self loginResult:result];

-(void)loginResult:(BOOL)result
{
    if(result == TRUE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Login successfully now call any method or do what ever you want");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Login unsuccessfull");
    }
}
```

Comment: When user login successfully save user_id in "NSUserDefaults" where ever you need in your application get it from UserDefaults.
Must remove it when user signout.